# findstr leading trailing spaces

Tags: escaping, whitespace, findstr

not a programmer, escape sequences very confusing.  Trying to clean a robocopy log based on words with leading AND trailing spaces.  Here's a sample from the log file.

```
  "line 2023   older      0 M:\RobinDocs\401K\2013 - Rollover Statements\Suburban Propane - Online Bill Payment_files\1.css"
  "line 4072  new Folder   637  M:\RobinDocs\A D V E R T I S I N G\Mail Designer 365 1.2.5\Mail Designer 365.app\Contents\Frameworks\iMedia.framework\Versions\A\Resources"*
  "line 6054  Folder637 M:\RobinDocs\A D V E R T I S I N G\Mail Designer 365 1.2.5\Mail Designer 365.app\Contents\Frameworks\iMedia.framework\Versions\A\Resources"*
```

Note the leading and trailing spaces.  While I want to get rid of lines containing '**older**' I don't want to lose those with '**F**older"

I have tried many different combinations of escape similar to the following.  But aargh can't find anything that discards the lines!  I get no error messages, but the lines are not discarded.  Windows 10 Home, all latest updates.

```
set vRoboLogFile=CrossBackups.log
findstr /v /c:" older "        %vRoboLogFile% > JUNK1%vRoboLogFile%
findstr /v /c:"\' 'older\' '"  %vRoboLogFile% > JUNK1%vRoboLogFile%
```

Any help appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, to clarify, the output should discard line 2023 but include the others.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you don't want the lines containing **older**, just search for the lines with **Folder**:

```
findstr /c:"Folder" %vRoboLogFile%
```